# Define a void two-way operation using Receive activity

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflowservice

How do I configure a workflow to expose a two-way void operation?

So that:
1) caller is blocked until operation completes and
2) caller is notified on exceptions (faults)

Using `Receive` + `SendReply` seems clunky. For one it adds unnecessary noise to the workflow diagram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Receive and SendReply pair is exactly how it is done. I agree that it adds a lot of unwanted complexity to you workflow. The best way to avoid that is to create a separate composite activity and wrap the Receive and SendReply in there. That way you see the simple composite activity on your workflow.